# How to not take part in another view , when TouchImageView drag in a view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two views(A and B) in screen. Each views contain TouchImageView. When I drag the image in A view to B, I want to not seem image on B view. But image seem A and B view. How can ignore seem on B?

---

Here is the touchimageview source code -  [TouchImageView source code](http://read.pudn.com/downloads164/sourcecode/macos/747251/MultiTouchDemo/Classes/TouchImageView.m__.htm)

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    TouchImageView *touch = [[TouchImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    touch.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"57" ofType:@"png"]];
    touch.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    [view addSubview:touch];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
```

I want to drag image, only view's in cordinate (0, 0, 300, 300).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [view setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

When I add this code, my problem is solved and image is not seen without view area.